# How to use a parameter in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Im pretty new to coding with JS/REACT. Can someone tell me why the parameter "keyword" in the following code isnt working as a parameter? Thank you!

```
function FillData(keyword) {
    return <div className="App">
                {
                    Data.map( datan => {
                        return(
                            <div className="box">
                            
                                {datan.keyword}
                                
                            </div>
                        )
                    } )
                }
    </div>
}
```

Tank you very much in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by `parameter`? What are you trying to do? What does it mean that it's not working? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Are you familiar with the way React uses [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)?

Comment: It would help a lot to add context. Show us `Data` and how `FillData` is used.

Comment: Im sorry: Data is an imported JSON-File and FillData is used to display content out of this JSON-File. I want to use "keyword" as a parameter to be able to use FillData as a function and give it the key in order for it to display the value from the JSON-File

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what your are looking for?

```
function FillData(keyword) {
    return <div className="App">
        {Data.map(datan => (
            <div className="box">
                {datan[keyword]}
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
}
```

If `FillData` is to be used as a component, you might need this instead:

```
function FillData(props) {
    return <div className="App">
        {Data.map(datan => (
            <div className="box">
                {datan[props.keyword]}
            </div>
        ))}
    </div>
}
```

Then you can use `FillData` like this:

```
<div><FillData keyword="foo" /></div>
```

Comment: If FillData takes `keyword` instead of [`props`](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html), it won't be a valid React Component.

Comment: that might help! can you tell me how i can pass the parameter when i use <FillData />?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you provide more context in your code to make it more readable:

If `keyword` is a prop which is supposed to extract a value from a `key` on an object then you do need to use the square bracket notation to extract the value from an object. In JavaScript unlike in many other languages you can use `square brackets` with a string key to extract values from an object or you can use `dot notation` to extract a hardcoded string key. For example, `myObj.keyword` will only ever get values at the `key` with the string name `"keyword"`. It is equivalent to: `myObj["keyword"]`. You might be hoping to extract a dynamic keyword from myObj. To do that you'll need to use `myObj[someKeyName]` and then you can dynamically define `var someKeyName = "what ever I want" (and allow it to be reassigned).

```
 {
                    Data.map( datan => {
                        return(
                            <div className="box">
                                {datan[keyword]}
                            </div>
                        )
                    } )
                }
```

But this would only work if `keyword` came back as a string. I recommend you `console.log` what keyword is and what its value is to make sure it is what you expect.

In React, all props come in under an object generally referred to as props. So in order to just get the `keyword` prop from your object you'll need: `props.keyword` or you can use destructuring to extract the `keyword` key value from the props object. So in all likelihood you meant to do: `function FillData({ keyword }) {` which would destructure the "keyword" out of the props object. I would also recommend calling it the `objectKey` instead of keyword which could be a lot more ambiguous.

I'm still not positive what you wanted to achieve, but most likely this will do something:

```
function FillData({ keyword }) {
// to make sure: I'd recommend:
// I'm not sure what Data is but I hope that it is an array.

// It is also possible that Data has not been resolved as a promise yet.
// For the following to work Data should be an array of objects
// all which have the dynamic `key` in the object.
// you should be able to do Data[0][keyword] and see a string.
console.log(keyword, Data)
    return (<div className="App">
                {Data.map( datan => {
                        return(
                            <div className="box">
                                {datan[keyword]}
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
    </div>)
}
```

This would work if you provide something like: `<FillData keyword="name" />`. Also, it assumes `Data` is defined as an array of objects with the name key filled like: `Data = [{name: 'hi' }, { name: 'something'}]`